# Entity Framework AddObject not adding Object to EntitySet

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have the following piece of code

```
private void DoAddPropertyType()
{
    var ctx = Globals.DbContext;
    var propType = new PropertyType()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "NewType",
        Description = "New Property Type",
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    ctx.AddToPropertyTypes(propType);
    PropertyTypes.Add(propType);
}
```

`Globals.DbContext` provides a static reference to the objectcontext initiated on startup. For some reason the `ctx.AddToPropertyTypes(propType);` bit does not add the entity to the context. If I breakpoint after that line and browse the `ctx.PropertyTypes` entity set it is not there. Any ideas?

EDIT 1:
If I add a `ctx.SaveChanges()` after the `ctx.AddToPropertyTypes(propType)` and step the actual adding appears to happen only once SaveChanges execute. This however does not suit my requirements as I want to first validate objects prior to saving and wanted to iterate through the entities in the entity set. Does any one know of an alternative approach?

Comment: Where do you call `SaveChanges`?

Comment: Only later after doing some validation. See Edit 1 above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that is the point of your issue. `ctx.PropertyTypes` is not a real collection - it is entrance to the database and your "browsing" actually executes query to the database where your new object was not yet stored. If you want to find a new object added to the context without saving it first you must search the object inside the `ObjectStateManager`:

```
var entity = ctx.ObjectStateManager
                .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                .Select(e => e.Entity)
                .OfType<PropertyType>()
                .SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == ...);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand EF a bit better now. You also showed me a way to get a list of all newly added entities which is helpful.